# Internet Explorer seperating lists differently in Twitter Widget Pro than all other browsers

Tags: plugins, list, twitter, browser-compatibility

I am having some trouble with the Twitter Widget Pro Plugin - for some reason in internet explorer if the first tweet has a link, it will make the link its own list item and add a bunch of extra padding above it. I have tried using different twitter feeds, changing around the widget settings but haven't had any luck figuring out what might be causing this.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Here is the link to see it - http://lynchbryan.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mark-up surrounding the widget is malformed. IE isn't handling this as well as other browsers.

```
<h1>Twitter</h1><h2><a href="http://twitter.com">Follow</h2>

        <div><h2><span class='twitterwidget twitterwidget-title'>
```

Note the opening anchor tag before "Follow". This is never closed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been working off too little sleep - it would be something dumb like that.